# ACM CCS Categorization code placement in latex file

Tags: pdftex, acmart

I want to place ACM CCS Categorization code in my document

```
  \begin{document}
  \begin{CCSXML}
  <ccs2012>
  <concept>
  <concept_id>10002951.10002952.10003219.10003218</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Information systems~Data cleaning</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
  </concept>
  </ccs2012>
  \end{CCSXML}
```

I placed the code before \maketitle. But I am getting the error as:

LaTeX Error: Environment CCSXML undefined. I went through previous answers and I got to know that CCSXML is a feature of acmart. But the template, I am using uses its documentclass:

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{ijamas}
```

How to resolve this issue. Latex template is available at:

```
http://www.ceser.in/ceserp/index.php/ijai/about/submissions#authorGuidelines
```

Instruction provided by the template:

For insertion into the ACM article LaTeX template click on the “View CCS TeX Code” link. The code you need to insert into your document will appear. Click into the code box and copy and paste into your document. Here is the sample TeX code from the above example:

```
\begin{CCSXML}
<ccs2012>
<concept>
<concept_id>10002951.10002952.10003190</concept_id>
<concept_desc>Information systems~Database management system 
 engines</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</concept>
<concept>
<concept_id>10010147.10010341.10010349.10010362</concept_id>
<concept_desc>Computing methodologies~Massively parallel and high- 
 performance simulations</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</concept>
<concept>
<concept_id>10003033.10003079</concept_id>
<concept_desc>Networks~Network performance evaluation</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>300</concept_significance>
</concept>

</ccs2012>
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc[500]{Information systems~Database management system engines}
\ccsdesc[500]{Computing methodologies~Massively parallel and high- 
 performance simulations}
\ccsdesc[300]{Networks~Network performance evaluation}
```

In word template, sample classification is given as:

Mathematics Subject Classification: 62J12, 62G99

Computing Classification System: I.4

My CCS Categories are: Information systems~Social networking sites, Information systems~Data cleaning
How to get CCS as I.4 for my categories. Need Help!!

Answer (score 0):

The `ijamas.cls` file is not based on the `acmart` class (which provides facilities to process the XML CSS classification). When you look at te sample provided in the author instruction you can notice the ACM classification is obtained by

```
\noindent\textbf{2000 Mathematics Subject Classification:} 49K05, 49K15, 49S05.
```

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: If your class file is not `acmart` (or based on it, or you copy the code provided in acmart to handle the classification), you cannot use snippet provided by the ACM tool.